# jQuery zclip not works on 1st click only

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

jJuery zclip not works on 1st click. It works on 2nd click?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  function initiateCopy(){

            $("a#copyDetails").zclip({
                path:'{% get_static_prefix %}scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy:function(){
                                        userDetails = '';
                                        user = JSON.parse($("#copyDetails").attr('rel'));
                                        $.each(user, function(key, value) {
                                            userDetails += key+": "+value;
                                        });
                                        return userDetails;
                                    }
            });

        } </script> <a id="copyDetails" href="javascript:initiateCopy()">Copy Details</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the handler for copy event is defined inside initiateCopy method.

The frist time you clic in a tag, you run initiateCopy and add event handler for zclip.
The second time, clip event is catch by zclip.

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  function initiateCopy(){

        $("a#copyDetails").zclip({
            path:'{% get_static_prefix %}scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){
                                    userDetails = '';
                                    user = JSON.parse($("#copyDetails").attr('rel'));
                                    $.each(user, function(key, value) {
                                        userDetails += key+": "+value;
                                    });
                                    return userDetails;
                                }
        });

    }
    initiateCopy(); </script> <a id="copyDetails">Copy Details</a>
```

if that works you can use onready or something more elegant.